# Why woocommerce block checkout button on checkout page?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I can't understand why woocommerce block this part of the screen by overlay block. In what cases is he can do it?

[screen checkout page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBy2y.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout contains several templates like totals & payment methods & addresses forms that updates in runtime via ajax.

When some part is updating, it adding `blockOverlay` until request will be complete.
As checkout page is loaded, all parts are updating by calling `$(body).trigger('update_checkout').`, that present at checkout.js

Infinite blocking overlay mark that there is some server error due request, so you need to check debug logs. Console probably contains 500 error also.

Comment: What if there is no apparent error? What happens when the shipping part takes too long to finish? Will it wait endlessly or will it timeout and leave the blockOverlay active? I deactivate one shipping module that obviously takes longer than all the others and suddenly no more hanging blockOverlay. I'm asking the client how important this slow one is for him. If he wants to keep it I would like to know how to set a longer timeout limit.